# Unable to retrieve meta data for model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to add scaffold item on the controller in Visual Studio 2013 Upgrade 5. But it gives an error like:

> "There was an error running the selected generator:'Unable to retrieve
>   meta data for XYZ.Models.Student'.One or more validation errors were
>   detected during model generation: XYZ.DAL.Student::EntityType
>   'Student' has no key defined.Define the key for this Entity Type.
>   Students: Entity Type: 'Student' is based on type 'Student' that has
>   no keys defined.

Model Class

```
public class Student
{
    public int SID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Record> Records { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: See the **Key** section in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj591583.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I assume SID is your primary key if so add following attribute:

```
[Key]
public int SID { get; set; }
```

note it is under : `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`